# SQL statement to find differences between two fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I am trying to find the difference of 11 feet or more between two fields (Both are Double types). For example, I have a field called shape_length and another field called station_length and I want to see if there are any differences of 11 feet or more between the two, and select those differences. I think it's a simple SQL statement in the "Select By Attributes dialog in ArcGIS but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Select by Attributes you could enter something like

`abs(shape_length - station_length) > 11`

which will select any feature where the difference between the two values is greater than 11.  The `abs` is for "absolute value" so makes it a positive value for assessing against the 11.